# Showing error while compiling. Showing no resource identifier found to weightsum and weight.

Tags: android

I having problem while running application. While running it is showing Error:(537) No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_weightsum' in package 'android'. I have tried by removing android:layout_weightsum(and android:layout_weight) to android:weightsum(and android:weight) but it has no effect.
The help would be appreciable. thanks in advance.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weightsum="6"
    android:id="@+id/LL1">
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/LL2">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ib1"
                android:src="@drawable/week"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sun"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/LL3">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ib2"
                android:src="@drawable/week"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mon"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/LL4">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ib3"
                android:src="@drawable/week"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/tue"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/LL5">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/ib4"
                android:src="@drawable/week"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/wed"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>          <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/LL6">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ib5"
            android:src="@drawable/week"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/thu"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>          <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/LL7">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ib6"
            android:src="@drawable/week"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fri"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It should be `weightSum` with a `capital s`.

Comment: Sorry but no effect i have already tired..

Comment: it is `android:weightSum="6"` (don't use `layout` word here) and `android:layout_weight="1"`

Comment: I am glad it helped you... :)  You can accept my answer so it is easier in future for someone to refer it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:weightSum="6"` (don't use `layout` word here) and `android:layout_weight="1"`